# How to use filter method for user model in another model (django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a custom user model:

```py
# accounts > models.py > ...
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
     [...]
    
    fallowing_tags = models.ManyToManyField('posts.tag', blank=True)
```

And I want to filter all users who fallowed a specific tag:

```py
from accounts.models import MyUser as User 
# ---- or -----
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()



class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    @property
    def fallowers(self):
        return User.objects.filter(fallowing_tags=self)
```

But the program gives an error:

```
  File "~/path/to/blog/accounts/models.py", line 13, in <module>
    from posts.models import Tag, Post
  File "~/path/to/blog/posts/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from accounts.models import MyUser as User 
ImportError: cannot import name 'MyUser' from partially initialized module 'accounts.models' (most likely due to a circular import) (~/path/to/blog/accounts/models.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django automatically adds a relation in reverse, so there is *no* need to add a `followers`, you can query with:

```
mytag.myuser_set.all()
```

If you want to change the name, you can set the [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), for example with:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
     # …
    
    fallowing_tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        'posts.tag',
        blank=True,
        related_name='users'
    )
```

Then you thus query with:

```
mytag.users.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `ImportError` and I think, it is because of this line `from accounts.models import MyUser as User`. It may be conflicting with django's inbuilt `User` model which is in `django.contrib.auth`. Try changing it to another name.

Well, i think you can also simply use `Myuser`.

Try:

```py
from accounts.models import MyUser
```

OR

```py
from accounts.models import MyUser as anyAnotherName
```

`Note:` Please don't give any name which has a possibility to conflict with django's libraries.